# Подключение к БД firebird через visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebird

Подскажите, какой драйвер нужен для работы с этой БД ? Ни один из стандартных драйверов не воспринимает её

[image]
Вылетает ошибка при создании модели EDM

Comment: tutorial [ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278405/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с Firebird вам необходимо установить:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
EntityFramework.Firebird
DDEX Provider
```

[DDEXProvider-3.0.2.0.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%203.0.2/DDEXProvider-3.0.2.0.7z/download)

[DDEXProvider-3.0.2.0-src.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%203.0.2/DDEXProvider-3.0.2.0-src.7z/download)

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient и EntityFramework.Firebird есть в NuGet.

Comment: А ddex provider - потом просто добавить в проект файлы ?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/278405/ - 7,8,9 пункты.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Возникла проблема. Пришлось переустановить визуалку, установил снова nuget, но теперь в nuget не находит файлы FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient и EntityFramework.Firebird

Comment: Это странно, потому что `NuGet` обращается к сайту `nuget.org` для получения списка доступных пакетов. Попробуйте самостоятельно вызвать установку через `Package Manager Console` командой - `PM> Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient`. Данную консоль можно открыть, выбрав в меню программы `Сервис->Диспетчер пакетов NuGet -> Консоль диспетчеров пакета`. Подробнее об установки через консоль на [оф. сайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/tools/package-manager-console)

Comment: Всё сделал, создал бд. Всё отлично. Но при создании модели EDM вылетает ошибка. Скриншот добавил. Визуалка 2013, firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить `ADO.NET Provider` (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient) и `DDEX Provider for Visual Studio`.

Можно скачать [тут](https://firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/).

Comment: `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` является необходимым и достаточным минимумом. В простейшем случае ничего подключать к проекту не нужно. Да и установить проще из `nuget`